# heart, heartrate and animated gear with css

Tags: css, css-animations

This is our logo: [image]

We would like to create it with css and animate the gear, but as you can see if you run my code, I am struggling with following:

- heart is not within the gear
- if I put div of heart in the gear its animating to, but only the gear should animate
- currently the heart-rate (blue line) isnt done with css, cause I dont know how to solve this

Do you know how to solve this?

```css
body{background: #fff;}

.parent{
  display: flex;
  height: 500px;
}

.gear{
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: auto;
  background: black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  animation-name: spin;
  animation-duration: 4s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
}

.gear .center{
  position: absolute;
  top: 25px;
  left: 25px;
  z-index: 10;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.tooth{
  position: absolute;
  top: -25px;
  left: 75px;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 45px;
  height: 250px;
  background:black;
}

.tooth:nth-child(2){
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.tooth:nth-child(3){
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.tooth:nth-child(4){
  transform: rotate(135deg);
}

@keyframes spin {
  from {transform: rotate(0deg); }
  to {transform: rotate(360deg);}
}

#heart {
 position: relative;
 width: 100px;
 height: 90px;
}

#heart:before,
#heart:after {
 position: absolute;
 content: "";
 left: 50px;
 top: 0;
 width: 50px;
 height: 80px;
 background: #1D74BA;
 -moz-border-radius: 50px 50px 0 0;
 border-radius: 50px 50px 0 0;
 -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
 -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
 -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
 -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
 transform: rotate(-45deg);
 -webkit-transform-origin: 0 100%;
 -moz-transform-origin: 0 100%;
 -ms-transform-origin: 0 100%;
 -o-transform-origin: 0 100%;
 transform-origin: 0 100%;
}

#heart:after {
 left: 0;
 -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
 -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
 -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
 -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
 transform: rotate(45deg);
 -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
 -moz-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
 -ms-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
 -o-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
 transform-origin :100% 100%;
}



svg.heart-rate{
  position: absolute;
  z-index:999;
  transform: scale(0.6);
  color:white;
  fill: currentColor;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div id="heart">
  <svg class="heart-rate" ersion="1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="150px" height="73px" viewBox="0 0 150 73" enable-background="new 0 0 150 73" xml:space="preserve">
    <polyline fill="none" stroke="#009B9E" stroke-width="3" stroke-miterlimit="10" points="0,45.486 38.514,45.486 44.595,33.324 50.676,45.486 57.771,45.486 62.838,55.622 71.959,9 80.067,63.729 84.122,45.486 97.297,45.486 103.379,40.419 110.473,45.486 150,45.486"
    />
  </svg>
</div>
  <div class="gear">
    <div class="center"></div>
    <div class="tooth"></div>
    <div class="tooth"></div>
    <div class="tooth"></div>
    <div class="tooth"></div>
  </div>  
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `position:absolute` on the heart and position it in the center of the parent using `top`,`left` and `transform`

```css
body {
  background: #fff;
}

.parent {
  display: flex;
  height: 500px;
  position:relative;
}

.gear {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: auto;
  background: black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  animation-name: spin;
  animation-duration: 4s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
}

.gear .center {
  position: absolute;
  top: 25px;
  left: 25px;
  z-index: 10;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.tooth {
  position: absolute;
  top: -25px;
  left: 75px;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 45px;
  height: 250px;
  background: black;
}

.tooth:nth-child(2) {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.tooth:nth-child(3) {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.tooth:nth-child(4) {
  transform: rotate(135deg);
}

@keyframes spin {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

#heart {
  position: absolute;
    width: 100px;
    height: 90px;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    z-index: 9999;
    margin-top:10px;
}

#heart:before,
#heart:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  left: 50px;
  top: 0;
  width: 50px;
  height: 80px;
  background: #1D74BA;
  -moz-border-radius: 50px 50px 0 0;
  border-radius: 50px 50px 0 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0 100%;
  -moz-transform-origin: 0 100%;
  -ms-transform-origin: 0 100%;
  -o-transform-origin: 0 100%;
  transform-origin: 0 100%;
}

#heart:after {
  left: 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
  -moz-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
  -ms-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
  -o-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
  transform-origin: 100% 100%;
}

svg.heart-rate {
     position: absolute;
    z-index: 999;
    color: white;
    fill: currentColor;
    left: 50%;
    top: 40%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%) scale(0.6);
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div id="heart">
    <svg class="heart-rate" ersion="1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="150px" height="73px" viewBox="0 0 150 73" enable-background="new 0 0 150 73" xml:space="preserve">
    <polyline fill="none" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="3" stroke-miterlimit="10" points="0,45.486 38.514,45.486 44.595,33.324 50.676,45.486 57.771,45.486 62.838,55.622 71.959,9 80.067,63.729 84.122,45.486 97.297,45.486 103.379,40.419 110.473,45.486 150,45.486"
    />
  </svg>
  </div>
  <div class="gear">
    <div class="center"></div>
    <div class="tooth"></div>
    <div class="tooth"></div>
    <div class="tooth"></div>
    <div class="tooth"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you very much for this! Do you have any idea how to make the light blue heartrate-line with css?

Comment: @KrystianManthey you can use the same thing, use absolute position and top/left to put where ever you want :), you can see my update!

Comment: I meant if you have any idea how to make this heartrate-svg with css instead? Cause actually it should be white and not light-blue
Anyway I will accept your answer! :-)

Comment: @KrystianManthey you can change the color of the svg `stroke="#fff"`, see my update